# OSX can't access localhost, only username.local

Tags: macos, web, localhost, host

I've been facing this problem in mountain lion 10.8.3 and I cannot seem to find an answer. The problem is that I can access my "localhost" using `username.local` or `http://127.0.0.1/` but not through `localhost`. I'm using apache 2.2 and virtualhostx, and for now is fine becuase I map every virtual host with a folder, but when developing in java, using Tomcat, I cannot access localhost, also there I have to access `username.local`..

my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

If I cant find a solution I only can think of a fresh reinstall.. And this will be very annoying..

Comment: Are you able to do `host localhost` from the terminal? What's the output?

Comment: Here's the output Host localhost not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

Comment: I got help from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068977/intellij-cant-start-simple-web-application-unable-to-ping-server-at-localhost

Answer (score 1):

check your httpd.conf for this line

# Virtual hosts

Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

i had the same issue. Then i discovered that the httod-vhosts.conf file was commented out when i upgraded my OS.