# IntelliJ Tomcat deployment process starts and freezes win7 x64

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am trying to deploy a web-app on `Tomcat 6` from `IntelliJ 13.1.4 Ultimate`. The deployment process starts and freezes before the point where it should actually deploy the war file  - "*Artifact is being deployed, please wait..*." However I am on `Windows 7 x64`. I tried all the SO thread advice till I found one where it advised to remove the `setenv.bat` from `C:\Programs\tomcat6\bin`. When I removed it, I still get the message, but my deployment works and I can launch the webapp fine.

My question is how to get rid of the message and the associated error?

The error is exactly similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068977/intellij-cant-start-simple-web-application-unable-to-ping-server-at-localhost) but on windows and editing the hostfile did not make a difference.
 
I keep getting this error:

> Artifact openmrs-webapp:war exploded: Server is not connected.
>   Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop,
>   reason: Unable to ping server at localhost:1099

I followed the documentation and there's no mention of JMX port [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-tomcat.html). Is this documentation correct?

[image: Tomcat settings]

Comment: Looks like a firewall issue. Disable your firewall and check if that fixes the problem. If it does then re-enable your firewall and add IntelliJ and java.exe  to exceptions

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Firewall state was off when i tried this