# javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: Catalina:type=Server occurs when I run debug using Tomcat7 in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

When I run debug using IntelliJ IDEA:

[image]

there comes an issue:

> It is possible to bind and connect to localhost:1099
>   at the same time - application server will probably compete with some other software on the port
>
> Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason:
>                   javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: Catalina:type=Server

And it did not open the broswer.

My Tomcat7 configuration is below:

[image]

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068977/intellij-cant-start-simple-web-application-unable-to-ping-server-at-localhost

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ, can't start simple web application: Unable to ping server at localhost:1099](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068977/intellij-cant-start-simple-web-application-unable-to-ping-server-at-localhost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restart my IntelliJ IDEA and Tomcat resolved this problem.

1) Restart IntelliJ IDEA
2) Restart Tomcat
3) Restart Mac

Answer (score 2):

Try a new vanilla Tomcat installation with unmodified configuration, configure IDEA to use this installation instead of the current one.

Some config or startup script modifications can break IDE integration.

Also check if the problem can be reproduced with the latest IntelliJ IDEA version, a related bug was fixed recently.

Answer (score 1):

Kill the process of Java, probably there's another instance of java running and it's conflicting to the recent java instance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is from 3 years ago but if anybody ends up finding this post I was able to solve this problem switching the JDK version from 11 to 8

PS: I was using TomEE WebProfile 7 and javax:javaee-api 7.0