# TomEE 10.0.27. No errors in stacktrace, but application cannot be reached

Tags: java, maven, apache-tomee

I'm attempting to run a program using TomEE 10.0.27. When I use the command -mvn clean package the build is successful without errors. When I attempt to run it using TomEE I also receive no errors, the only thing of note is that Intellij returns: "Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason: Unable to ping server at localhost:1099". I have attempted as many solutions as I could find, mainly in this post [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068977/intellij-cant-start-simple-web-application-unable-to-ping-server-at-localhost)

Underneath I have also added part of the stacktrace, as it might be helpful

```
********************************************************************************
19-Mar-2024 19:48:19.810 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> OpenEJB http://tomee.apache.org/
19-Mar-2024 19:48:19.810 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> Startup: Tue Mar 19 19:48:19 CET 2024
19-Mar-2024 19:48:19.810 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> Copyright 1999-2021 (C) Apache TomEE Project, All Rights Reserved.
19-Mar-2024 19:48:19.810 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> Version: 9.1.2
19-Mar-2024 19:48:19.810 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> Build date: 20231212
19-Mar-2024 19:48:19.810 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> Build time: 04:08
19-Mar-2024 19:48:19.810 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> ********************************************************************************
19-Mar-2024 19:48:19.811 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> openejb.home = C:\Users\de Vries\Documents\HBO-ICT\DEA\tools\apache-tomee-plus-9.1.2
19-Mar-2024 19:48:19.811 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> openejb.base = C:\Users\de Vries\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.3\tomcat\6f7ebe16-32cf-4863-b12b-5340167249a6
19-Mar-2024 19:48:19.812 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.initializeOWB Created new singletonService org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@61e94def
19-Mar-2024 19:48:19.815 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.initializeOWB Succeeded in installing singleton service
19-Mar-2024 19:48:19.848 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.init TomEE configuration file is 'C:\Users\de Vries\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.3\tomcat\6f7ebe16-32cf-4863-b12b-5340167249a6\conf\tomee.xml'
19-Mar-2024 19:48:19.899 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=Tomcat Security Service, type=SecurityService, provider-id=Tomcat Security Service)
19-Mar-2024 19:48:19.902 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=Default Transaction Manager, type=TransactionManager, provider-id=Default Transaction Manager)
19-Mar-2024 19:48:19.905 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog.info Using 'openejb.system.apps=true'
19-Mar-2024 19:48:19.906 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=Default Singleton Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Singleton Container)
19-Mar-2024 19:48:19.939 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating TransactionManager(id=Default Transaction Manager)
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.008 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating SecurityService(id=Tomcat Security Service)
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.056 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Container(id=Default Singleton Container)
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.075 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Assembling app: openejb
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.149 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog.info Using 'openejb.jndiname.format={deploymentId}{interfaceType.openejbLegacyName}'
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.164 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder.bind Jndi(name=openejb/DeployerBusinessRemote) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer)
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.165 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder.bind Jndi(name=global/openejb/openejb/openejb/Deployer!org.apache.openejb.assembler.Deployer) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer)
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.169 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder.bind Jndi(name=global/openejb/openejb/openejb/Deployer) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer)
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.171 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder.bind Jndi(name=openejb/ConfigurationInfoBusinessRemote) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo)
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.171 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder.bind Jndi(name=global/openejb/openejb/openejb/Deployer!org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.cmd.ConfigurationInfo) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo)
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.185 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Created Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo, ejb-name=openejb/Deployer, container=Default Singleton Container)
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.188 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Created Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer, ejb-name=openejb/Deployer, container=Default Singleton Container)
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.188 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo, ejb-name=openejb/Deployer, container=Default Singleton Container)
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.188 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer, ejb-name=openejb/Deployer, container=Default Singleton Container)
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.192 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.deployMBean Deployed MBean(openejb.user.mbeans:application=openejb,group=org.apache.openejb.assembler.monitoring,name=JMXDeployer)
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.195 WARNING [main] org.apache.batchee.container.services.ServicesManager.init You didn't specify org.apache.batchee.jmx.application and JMX is already registered, skipping
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.197 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Deployed Application(path=openejb)
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.252 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.ServiceManager.initServer Creating ServerService(id=cxf)
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.517 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.ServiceManager.initServer Creating ServerService(id=cxf-rs)
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.589 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.start   ** Bound Services **
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.589 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.printRow   NAME                 IP              PORT  
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.589 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.start -------
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.589 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.start Ready!
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.590 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Server initialization in [1744] milliseconds
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.629 INFO [main] org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBNamingContextListener.bindResource Importing a Tomcat Resource with id 'UserDatabase' of type 'org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase'.
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.629 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Resource(id=UserDatabase)
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.644 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Starting service [Catalina]
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.644 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/10.0.27 (9.1.2)]
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.724 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
19-Mar-2024 19:48:20.747 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Server startup in [157] milliseconds
19-Mar-2024 19:48:30.737 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\de Vries\Documents\HBO-ICT\DEA\tools\apache-tomee-plus-9.1.2\webapps\manager]
19-Mar-2024 19:48:30.747 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.init ------------------------- localhost -> /manager
19-Mar-2024 19:48:30.940 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication Configuring enterprise application: C:\Users\de Vries\Documents\HBO-ICT\DEA\tools\apache-tomee-plus-9.1.2\webapps\manager
19-Mar-2024 19:48:30.992 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder.build Enterprise application "C:\Users\de Vries\Documents\HBO-ICT\DEA\tools\apache-tomee-plus-9.1.2\webapps\manager" loaded.
19-Mar-2024 19:48:30.993 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Assembling app: C:\Users\de Vries\Documents\HBO-ICT\DEA\tools\apache-tomee-plus-9.1.2\webapps\manager
19-Mar-2024 19:48:31.055 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ValidatorBuilder.getConfig Ignoring XML Configuration for validator org.apache.bval.jsr.ConfigurationImpl
19-Mar-2024 19:48:31.088 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWebApps using context file C:\Users\de Vries\Documents\HBO-ICT\DEA\tools\apache-tomee-plus-9.1.2\webapps\manager\META-INF\context.xml
19-Mar-2024 19:48:31.089 WARNING [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.batchee.container.services.ServicesManager.init You didn't specify org.apache.batchee.jmx.application and JMX is already registered, skipping
19-Mar-2024 19:48:31.090 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Deployed Application(path=C:\Users\de Vries\Documents\HBO-ICT\DEA\tools\apache-tomee-plus-9.1.2\webapps\manager)
19-Mar-2024 19:48:31.263 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.tomee.microprofile.openapi.MicroProfileOpenApiRegistration.onStartup Registering OpenAPI servlet on /openapi for application /manager
19-Mar-2024 19:48:31.265 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.myfaces.ee.MyFacesContainerInitializer.onStartup Using org.apache.myfaces.ee.MyFacesContainerInitializer
19-Mar-2024 19:48:31.356 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
19-Mar-2024 19:48:31.571 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\de Vries\Documents\HBO-ICT\DEA\tools\apache-tomee-plus-9.1.2\webapps\manager] has finished in [833] ms
```